# Storing sort order for items held in an HABTM association - CakePHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql, activerecord, cakephp

In an ActiveRecord (CakePHP flavored) setup I have a HasAndBelongsToMany association setup on Videos and Bins: A Bin can store *n* references to Videos, and Videos can belong to *n* Bins.

I need to be able to manually set and store the display order of the Videos within a particular Bin (so the client can have his Videos in a particular order within the Bin.) My initial thought is to create a field in Bin that stores an array of Video IDs in the order they need to appear. Is this the most efficient way to handle this?

If so, when I then get the HABTM query result, what is the cleanest/most efficient way to re-order the returned query to match the sorted array of ID's?

The Videos associated with a Bin are returned as an array:

```
[Video] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 49b2de95-0338-48b9-bc88-01ba35664358
                        ...

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 49b1ccad-b770-410e-be46-03a035664358
                        ...
            )
```

Or is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do without using HABTM associations?

Thanks in advance -

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What to do when HABTM becomes complicated?

By default when saving a HasAndBelongsToMany relationship, Cake will delete all rows on the join table before saving new ones. For example if you have a Club that has 10 Children associated. You then update the Club with 2 children. The Club will only have 2 Children, not 12.

Also note that if you want to add more fields to the join (when it was created or meta information) this is possible with HABTM join tables, but it is important to understand that you have an easy option.

HasAndBelongsToMany between two models is in reality shorthand for three models associated through both a hasMany and a belongsTo association.

Consider this example:

```
Child hasAndBelongsToMany Club
```

Another way to look at this is adding a Membership model

```
Child hasMany Membership
Membership belongsTo Child, 
ClubClub hasMany Membership.
```

These two examples are almost the exact same. They use the same amount and named fields in the database and the same amount of models. The important differences are that the "join" model is named differently and it's behavior is more predictable.

In your example, you need a way to add and remove without editing other users Video links, therefore standard habtm will not suit you very well. Create a model for this "join" similar to the Membership model described above. Further, if you added a weight field, you could use the [ordered behavior](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/orderedbehavior-2-1) (that I wrote) to order each set of videos per bin. Then you would use the following fields

```
id, bin_id, video_id, weight
```

And set up bin_id as the 'foreign_key' in the behavior configuartion. Good luck

Comment: Right, so instead of using the built in HABTM associations your method creates a join table to associate a record containing metadata (weight, etc) with each Video, providing fine grained control over the query. So I could order the 'Membership' records by `weight` to get my correct order.

Comment: well im not sure if you see it correctly. What I propose is to move away from habtm, and thus HABTM, and just make a third model that belongsTo Video and Bin, and is ordered.

Comment: No I think we're saying the same thing. The new third model stores any metadata the Bin needs about the Video and I can sort it by whatever field.

But to an earlier point of yours: Couldn't I add a field 'order' to the VideosBins HABTM join table and then sort the retrieved data by that additional field using Set::sort (from Herr Lecter below)?

Comment: heh i mean and thus "join table", sorry for the double habtm. maybe you could, but, 1. Why? 2. How cake add and delete "joins" will cause you trouble. 3. PHP sorting is much more costly then letting sql take care of it.

Answer (score 2):

Well I tried to solve just this problem and think I found the simplest solution possible:

When saving a new order of the related models you delete the existing relations and add the new ones in the desired order. This means the ids created run in your sort order and you can simply sort by id to display the order.

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Item' => array(
        'order' => 'ItemFoldersItem.id ASC, Item.name DESC',
    )
);
```

Pretty simple isn't it?

Comment: well the only problem is that the second sorting is always ignored as ids are of course unique. so you still have to take care about a default sorting order that should not be by the ids.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about "most efficient" way to implement what you want, that depends on your whole application and what you want to accomplish. I'd just keep in mind that the most simple solution is often the best.

However, I can give you a tip for sorting your Video array! It is fairly easy:

```
$yourData = Set::sort($yourData, '/Video/id', 'asc');
```

Take a look at the [Set class](http://api.cakephp.org/class/set) for more candy. :)

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem, but thanks for the heads up. I've used Set for other things but haven't done too much sorting with it (mostly Set::extract). I think I might be able to use Set::sort to partially solve the problem (see comment to A. Morland above)